# how to wire all the django apps

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new with Django, I've been reading and watching videos but there is one thing that is confusing me. It is related to the apps. I've watched a video where a guy said that is convenient to have apps that do a single thing, so if I have a big project, I will have a lot of apps. I made an analogy to a bunch of classes, where each app would be a class with their own functions and elements, is this a correct interpretation? In this case, is there like an app where I have like a main method in a class? I mean, I don't know how to wire all the applications I have, is there like a principal app in charge of manage the others? or how does it work?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have `base` app if you want to, but you don't need one. All apps are wired when you declare them in the INSTALLED_APPS in the settings, each app has a urls.py file that will catch the route and call one of the views in that app if there's a match.

I use a base app to define global templates, global static files, helpers.

Hope this helps

Comment: interesting, is there a place where I could read more about projects with lot of apps? the documentation is very basic, and couldn't find anything else.

Comment: I like this book http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-5-e-book-bundle I found it quite useful for people starting with django